# How to pass and use parameters to a MySqlOperator

Tags: airflow

Given a `MySqlOperator` and an sql query how do i pass a `parameter` and use it?
Here is my code which doesn't work. I am trying to pass the table name as a parameter.

```
UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE {table} SET version=version+1 WHERE id='x'"

update_row = MySqlOperator(
                dag=dag,
                task_id='update_row',
                mysql_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
                parameters={'table': 'hello_world'},
                database=MY_DATABASE,
                sql=UPDATE_SQL,
                )
```

I could not find any examples on how to use the parameters in the Operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE {{ params.table }} SET version=version+1 WHERE id='x'"

update_row = MySqlOperator(
                dag=dag,
                task_id='update_row',
                mysql_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
                params={"table": "hello_world"},
                database=MY_DATABASE,
                sql=UPDATE_SQL,
                )
```

[image]